# AsyncQueue Failed to persist write: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write unit test for my Firestore rules.
It loosely based on https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing/blob/master/unit-test-security-rules/test/firestore.spec.js

and following https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

It has 3 test cases 2 of them pass fine.
3rd test is that the user can't delete a document but `deleteDoc` seems to throw an error.

```
[2022-10-11T19:56:27.376Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.11.0): AsyncQueue Failed to persist write: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
[2022-10-11T19:56:27.377Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.11.0): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at ObjectMap.mapKeyFn (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/model/collections.ts:86:16)
    at ObjectMap.get (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/obj_map.ts:49:21)
    at ObjectMap.has (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/obj_map.ts:63:17)
    at /Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/local_documents_view.ts:190:21
    at /Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/sorted_map.ts:141:7
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/sorted_map.ts:324:7)
    at SortedMap.inorderTraversal (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/sorted_map.ts:136:42)
    at SortedMap.forEach (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/sorted_map.ts:140:10)
    at LocalDocumentsView.populateOverlays (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/local_documents_view.ts:189:10)
    at LocalDocumentsView.getOverlayedDocuments (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/local_documents_view.ts:174:17)
    at /Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/local_store_impl.ts:350:48
    at /Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/persistence_promise.ts:136:42
    at PersistencePromise.wrapUserFunction (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/persistence_promise.ts:120:22)
    at PersistencePromise.wrapSuccess (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/persistence_promise.ts:136:19)
    at PersistencePromise.next (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/persistence_promise.ts:94:21)
    at /Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/local_store_impl.ts:346:10
    at MemoryPersistence.runTransaction (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/memory_persistence.ts:175:12)
    at localStoreWriteLocally (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/local/local_store_impl.ts:327:6)
    at syncEngineWrite (/Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/core/sync_engine_impl.ts:462:26)
    at /Users/gustek/my-github/db-unit-tests-example/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/core/firestore_client.ts:455:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

This is my test code

```js
import {assertFails, assertSucceeds} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import firebase = require("@firebase/rules-unit-testing");
import fs = require("fs");
import {setDoc, deleteDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

const PROJECT_ID = "firestore-emulator-example";


describe("Rules test", function() {
  let env: firebase.RulesTestEnvironment;

  before(async () => {
  // Load the rules file before the tests begin
    const rules = fs.readFileSync("../firestore.rules", "utf8");
    env = await firebase.initializeTestEnvironment(
        {
          projectId: PROJECT_ID,
          firestore: {rules},
        }
    );
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
  // Clear the database between tests
    await env.clearFirestore();
  });

  it("require users to log in before creating a profile", async () => {
    const userId = "alice";
    const context = env.authenticatedContext(userId);
    await assertSucceeds(
        setDoc(
            context.firestore().doc(`/privateProfiles/${userId}`),
            {}
        )
    );
  });

  it("edit only your own profile", async () => {
    const alice = "alice";
    const bob = "bob";
    const aliceContext = env.authenticatedContext(alice);
    const bobContext = env.authenticatedContext(bob);
    await assertSucceeds(
        setDoc(
            aliceContext.firestore().doc(`/privateProfiles/${alice}`),
            {}
        )
    );
    await assertFails(
        setDoc(
            bobContext.firestore().doc(`/privateProfiles/${alice}`),
            {}
        )
    );
  });

  it("can't directly delete a profile", async () => {
    const alice = "alice";
    const aliceContext = env.authenticatedContext(alice);
    const db = aliceContext.firestore();
    await assertSucceeds(
        setDoc(
            db.doc(`/privateProfiles/${alice}`),
            {"smth": 1}
        )
    );
    await assertFails(
        deleteDoc(
            db.doc(`/privateProfiles/${alice}`)
        )
    );
  });
});
```

and full code at https://github.com/GustekDev/db-unit-tests-example

running the tests using `firebase emulators:exec ./test.sh` from inside `functions` directory.

Am I doing something wrong, or is that a bug in the Firebase?

Comment: What syntax version are you using? V8 or V9? It seems that there's a mixup in both versions.

Comment: Thank you. Docs have a code that does not compile `assertSucceeds(setDoc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { ... })` and I incorrectly "fixed" it. It should be `assertSucceeds(setDoc(doc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { ... }))`

Comment: Is your issue already resolved? If so, please post your answer so that other community members with similar questions will find your answer helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing

```js
assertSucceeds(setDoc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { ... })
```

to

```js
assertSucceeds(setDoc(doc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { ... }))
```